# ¿Es posible utilizar una librería de Windows desde una aplicación de escritorio JAVA?

Tags: java, .net, windows

Estoy buscando una forma nativa de usar una biblioteca DLL de Windows desde una aplicación de escritorio Jav como si fuera un *".jar"*.

Estoy utilizando el IDE [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) y el componente DLL es uno antiguo que originalmente se implementó como un componente de *OCX* y se migró a *DLL* más tarde.

Por supuesto que estuve navegando en la web, pero aún no encontré nada.

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama JNI: Java Native Interface. Asimismo, hay otro "nuevo" llamado JNA. Si conoces inglés, te recomiendo leer [Use JNI instead of JNA to call native code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1556421/1065197) y [JNI vs. JNA performance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22288909/1065197)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Luiggi Mendoza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Échale un vistazo a esta entrada de blog:

- http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/

Hace uso del [jna](/questions/tagged/jna) (Java Native Access):

- https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/package-summary.html

Debes hacer uso de `Native.loadLibrary`:

- https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.Map)

Solo hay que tener especial cuidado con la conversión de tipos de datos.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Óscar!. Habíamos visto JNA pero no sabíamos que con una librería de Windows podíamos usarla también.

Comment: En el peor de los casos tienes que decidir entre dos soluciones: usar `Native.loadLibrary` y asignar las llamadas a los métodos con tipos de datos nativos de Java (implementando llamadas sencillas y recompilando el DLL original), o bien desarrollar un DLL intermedio que haga conversión de datos entre los nativos de Java y los que requiere tu DLL original. Lo ideal es la primera solución, pero dependiendo de cada caso particular una solución es mejor que la otra.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia. En nuestro caso todavía tenemos personal trabajando con la tecnología .Net en la oficina, y podrían encargarse de una migración del componente para aplicar esa primera opción que comentas ya que, efectivamente, parece la más óptima.